# Why popup window stay front after refresh parent window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-chrome

I have a window X,when i click button on X,
a popup window Y will show in the click event using "window.open".
When i click button on Y, use "window.opener" to refresh window X's content in the JS.
At the same time I want to send window Y to the X's back.

env: chrome 73 HTML5 Asp.Net

It's OK in IE11 automatically,but failed in Chrome.
I have tried serveral ways to apv it，exp：opener.focus and window.blur in popup window.but still failed.

It seems very clear to me what opener and focus are supposed to do, but window.opener.focus doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I saw the link. Indeed it's same problem...

Comment: But it's chrome 73 now,is there some different for this problem? @mooga